# How to use mutate() +across() only for specific rows

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

The data:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~name, ~val.I, ~val.V, ~`val.%`,
  "Peter", 123, 12.4, 14,
  "Peter in %", 111, 532, 57,
  "Harald", 2222, 3333, 444,
  "Harald in %", 22, 15, 203,
)
```

I would like to mutate  (function: divide the value by 100) that contain `.I` and `.V`, but only for rows that contain the string `in %` in the column *name*. I know an easy for-loop solution, but could not figure out it with `dplyr`. Any hints much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `dplyr` option with `mutate` and `across` using `matches` for the specific columns. You can use the following code:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(matches(".I|.V"), ~ if_else(row_number() %in% grep("in %", name), ./100, .)))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  name          val.I   val.V `val.%`
  <chr>         <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 Peter        123      12.4       14
2 Peter in %     1.11    5.32      57
3 Harald      2222    3333        444
4 Harald in %    0.22    0.15     203
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution in `base R`:

```r
library(tibble)

df <- tribble(
  ~name, ~val.I, ~val.V, ~`val.%`,
  "Peter", 123, 12.4, 14,
  "Peter in %", 111, 532, 57,
  "Harald", 2222, 3333, 444,
  "Harald in %", 22, 15, 203,
)

df[grepl("in \\%",df$name), grep(".V|.I", names(df))] <- 
       df[grepl("in \\%",df$name), grep(".V|.I", names(df))] /100

#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>   name          val.I   val.V `val.%`
#>   <chr>         <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 Peter        123      12.4       14
#> 2 Peter in %     1.11    5.32      57
#> 3 Harald      2222    3333        444
#> 4 Harald in %    0.22    0.15     203
```

---

With `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 mutate(across(contains(c(".V",".I")), ~ if_else(grepl("in \\%",name), .x/100, .x)))

#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>   name          val.I   val.V `val.%`
#>   <chr>         <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 Peter        123      12.4       14
#> 2 Peter in %     1.11    5.32      57
#> 3 Harald      2222    3333        444
#> 4 Harald in %    0.22    0.15     203
```

Comment: Thanks a lot both @Quinten and @Paul, I almost got there myself with the ifelse, but used `str_detect()` in the if_else which obviously did't work (And now I understand why :)

Comment: You are welcome, @Julian! With `str_detect` also works: `df %>% 
  mutate(across(contains(c(".V",".I")),~ if_else(str_detect(df$name, "in \\%"),.x/100,.x)))`

Comment: Ah amazing, thanks Paul! It even works with `str_detect(name, "in %")` :)

Comment: True, @Julian! I have just removed `df$` from my `grepl` -- it also works.